# How can I add dynamic content to "First Row As Header" condition in Azure Data Factory Dataset?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In a dataset, I can see that I can add dynamic content in the First Row as Header box:

[image]

My question is can I use dynamic content in a way that if a column header is empty in the csv then I can add a custom name. If all the column names are there, it would take the first row as is?

Asking because I have some files with 1/2 empty column names.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is can I use dynamic content in a way that if a column header is empty in the csv then I can add a custom name. If all the column names are there, it would take the first row as is?

No,because dynamic content must return boolean value,you can't replace empty column name with your custom name.

As a workaround,you can use data flow.

Below is my test sample:

*My data in csv file:*

```
fieldA,,fieldB,,fieldC
1,2,3,4,5
```

**Setting of source of dataset:**

[image]

**ADF will auto generate column name when your column name is empty,like _c1**

[image]

**Then you can use `DerivedColumn`:**

[image]

**Finally:you can use `select` or `sink mapping`,delete columns which are generated by ADF.**

Comment: using a data flow instead of copy activity worked. Thanks!